# How to use a custom made library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a AWS dependency layer on on folder `nodejs/`

There is node_modules/ and package.json with `npm dependencies`

I created a folder called `utils/` and my file is `util.js`

Since it's a layer on AWS, I import using `const utils = require('/opt/nodejs/utils/util');` on my `app.js`

Problem is that my test cases started failing `Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/utils/util' from 'backend/lambdas/cars/app.js'`

How can I fix my test case??

```
const app = require('./app');

describe('lambda', function () {
    it('something', async () => {
        const response = await app.lambdaHandler();
        ....
    });
});
```

app.js

```
const httpStatusCode = require('http-status-codes');
const cors = require('/opt/nodejs/utils/util');

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {
return {
    statusCode: httpStatusCode.OK
 };
};
```

**PS: This `nodejs` folder is on the same level as the `lambdas` folder**

Answer (score 0):

You should import like this `const utils = require('../nodejs/utils/util')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).